# Making alias that have similar attributes and conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm making query that needs to output new alias with different, but similar, conditions.

There are two tables; one for person, product, and sale. They should have something like following:

```
person = (personID, personName, isValidPerson)
product = (productID, productName)
sale = (productID, tradeTime, customerID, employeeID)
```

My goal is to output `productID, productName, customerName, and employeeName` for specific time. It also has to be distinct.

As you can see from above table, we don't have attributes called `customerName` and `employeeName`. I understand that I have to make alias for those two attributes, but I can't get them to work for some reason and gives me an error.

So far, I tried to use `AS` statement by linking person and sale table with two conditions.

To elaborate on this, I did the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.productID, prod.productName,
                psn.personName AND psn.personID = s.customerID AS customerName,
                psn.personName AND psn.personID = s.employeeID AS employeeName,
FROM person psn, product prod, sale s
WHERE s.tradeTime < '2017-01-01 11:00:00';
```

However, I am keep getting an error for assigning alias to customerName and employeeName column. I attempted to do `psn.personID AS customerName` and same for `employeeName` and declare from WHERE. However, I had issue with this as well since both `customerName` and `employeeName` has issue recognizing which `psn.personName` to choose.

If I can get this right, I am hoping that all four attributes mentioned above should display its results for certain time range that's before '2017-01-01 11:00:00'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use join like below

```
     Select pr.productID  pr.productname
     ,p.personName as customername,
     P1.personName as employeeName
    from sale s join product pr
  On s.productID=pr.productID
   Left Join person p on s.customerID=p.personID
  Left Join person p1 on s.employeeID=p1.personID
```

Here you need two times join with the person table ,1st for customaername and 2nd for employeeName that's why I use alias in time of join